# Losing background image in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, tablet

I need to lose the background image in mobile view but my @media query seems to be ignoring the request, this also applies to an image I am using too?

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    .logo {
    background-image:URL(img/allthingslogoalt.gif);
    height:32px;
    width:222px;
    margin:110px auto 0 auto;
    background-size:444px 64px;
}

}   

}


@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {

#allthingsus {
    background-color:#FFF;


}

}


@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#allthingsus {
    background-color:#FFF;


}
}
```

Here is the main css:

```
.logo {
    background-image:URL(img/allthingslogo.gif);
    height:64px;
    width:444px;
    margin:180px auto 0 auto;
}

#allthingsus {
    background-color:#FFF;
    background-image:URL(img/greypointer.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;


}
```

i am not sure how to cure this problem? I have tried adding it as a class, an ID, changing the min/max heights but nothing changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the bit that is attempting to change your background image:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#allthingsus {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

You're only setting a background-color and therefore not changing the background-image. You need to set `background-image: none;` for this media query.

**Edit**

Couldn't really test using the media query `max-device-width` so have done a fiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/rnewport/em35H/1/) using `max-width` instead and it seemed to be working ok for that

Comment: The background is still there? It is almost like it is ignoring the CSS media query?

Comment: Apologies if this is an obvious point but you are trying to remove 'greypointer.gif' and not 'allthingslogo.gif' aren't you?

Comment: I sure am! :) I think I have figured it out...but what do you suggest?